# How to check if a list in python and row in PostgreSQL table contain same files?

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a row named `filename` in postgresql table named `xml_joblist` which contain many files, and a list named `files_name` in python which contain several files that are sorted after some process. I want to compare `filename` & `files_name` and check whether there are any files matching.

```
|filename |
|---------|
|file_111 |
|file_555 |
|file_888 |
|file_333 | 
|file_445 |
|   .     |
|   .     |
| goes-on |
```

the above given is the `filename` row in postgresql table

```
files_name = [file_789, file_456, file_555, file_111]
```

the above given is the files_name list i python

How can i write a sql statement to do this process in python?

Expected result:

```
matchin_files = [file_555, file_111]
```

Comment: You mean a column in postgres?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect to the postgres db

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, select, Table, Column, String, MetaData,  Float, Integer
from sqlalchemy.engine import URL

# Creating URL object

url_object  = URL.create(
    "postgresql",
    username="YourUserName",
    password="YourPassword",  # plain (unescaped) text
    host="YourHostName",
    database="YourDBName",
)

# Define the Connection Object
db = create_engine(url_object)
```

Get the `xml_joblist` table

```
# Create the Metadata Object
meta = MetaData(bind=db)
MetaData.reflect(meta)

# Get the `xml_joblist` table from the Metadata object
xml_joblist = meta.tables['xml_joblist']
```

Select `filename` from `xml_joblist` table and compare it to `files_name`

```
# List with File names
files_name = ['file_789', 'file_456', 'file_555', 'file_111']

# Read
with db.connect() as conn:
    #SELECT xml_joblist.filename FROM xml_joblist WHERE xml_joblist.filename IN (files_name)
    select_statement = select(xml_joblist.c.filename).where(xml_joblist.c.filename.in_(files_name))
    result_set = conn.execute(select_statement)
    matchin_files = result_set.scalars().all()
```

This gives `matchin_files` as a list like this-

```
['file_111', 'file_555']
```

Answer (score 3):

Set up table:

```
create table xml_joblist(filename varchar);
insert into xml_joblist values ('file_111'), ('file_555'), ('file_888'), ('file_333'), ('file_445');
```

Python code:

```
import psycopg2
con = psycopg2.connect(dbname="test", host='localhost', user='postgres', port=5432)
cur = con.cursor()

files_name = ["file_789", "file_456", "file_555", "file_111"]

cur.execute("select filename from xml_joblist where filename = ANY(%s)", [files_name])

matching_files = [row[0] for row in cur.fetchall()]

matching_files
['file_111', 'file_555']
```

This uses `psycopg2` [list adaptation](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#adapt-list):

> Python lists are converted into PostgreSQL ARRAYs:

> > > cur.mogrify("SELECT %s;", ([10, 20, 30], ))
> > > 'SELECT ARRAY[10,20,30];'

> Note

> You can use a Python list as the argument of the IN operator using the PostgreSQL ANY operator.

> ids = [10, 20, 30]
> cur.execute("SELECT * FROM data WHERE id = ANY(%s);", (ids,))

> Furthermore ANY can also work with empty lists, whereas IN () is a SQL syntax error.

> Note

> ...

to select those file names that are in the `file_names` list that are also in the `xml_joblist` table using the [ANY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.30.16) operator:

> 9.24.3. ANY/SOME (array)

> expression operator ANY (array expression)

> expression operator SOME (array expression)

> The right-hand side is a parenthesized expression, which must yield an array value. The left-hand expression is evaluated and compared to each element of the array using the given operator, which must yield a Boolean result. The result of ANY is “true” if any true result is obtained. The result is “false” if no true result is found (including the case where the array has zero elements).

> If the array expression yields a null array, the result of ANY will be null. If the left-hand expression yields null, the result of ANY is ordinarily null (though a non-strict comparison operator could possibly yield a different result). Also, if the right-hand array contains any null elements and no true comparison result is obtained, the result of ANY will be null, not false (again, assuming a strict comparison operator). This is in accordance with SQL's normal rules for Boolean combinations of null values.

> SOME is a synonym for ANY.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using psycopg2 directly, you can use its tuple to `SELECT IN` capabilities. You then retrieve the file name directly with a list comprehension.

See the following demo a table that contains `file_100` through to `file_109`.

```py
# setup
import psycopg2

con = psycopg2.connect(
    host="localhost",
    port="5432",
    database="postgres",
    user="postgres",
    password="postgres",
)

cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE xml_joblist (filename VARCHAR(10))")
cur.executemany(
    "INSERT INTO xml_joblist (filename) VALUES (%s)",
    [(f"file_10{n}",) for n in range(10)],
)

# query
files_name = ["file_103", "file_107", "file_108"]  # keep as list or assign tuple directly

cur.execute(
    "SELECT filename FROM xml_joblist WHERE filename IN %s",
    (tuple(files_name),)
)  # convert files_name to tuple if not already a tuple
results = cur.fetchall()  # [('file_103',), ('file_107',), ('file_108',)]
matching_files = [t[0] for t in results]  # ['file_103', 'file_107', 'file_108'

# closing
con.close()
```

If you use anything else (like SQLAlchemy), please leave a comment.

Comment: what changes should I make if I'm using SQLAlchemy?

Comment: @AstroInTheOcean see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75035291/17676984).

Answer (score 0):

you can use SQLAlchemy IN comparison operator([check here for more inforamtion!](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/operators.html#in-comparisons))

```
stmt = select(xml_joblist.filename).where(xml_joblist.filename.in_(files_name))
result = conn.execute(stmt)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using a library such as psycopg2, then the cur.execute method() will return you a [list of tuples](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.fetchall), with each tuple containing a single item.

So essentially your question simplifies to
How to compare a list of tuples against a list.

One of the ways to do so is to use something like below

```
list_of_tuples = [(i,) for i in range(1000000)]
my_list = list(range(1000000))

if list_of_tuples == [(elem,) for elem in my_list]:
    print("The lists are equal")
```

Other way is to use set.

```
list_of_tuples = [(i,) for i in range(1000000)]
my_list = list(range(1000000))

if set(list_of_tuples) == set(my_list):
    print("The lists are equal")
```

Comment: This is a terrible idea, what if the `xml_joblist` has 1B records ? Your answer would fetch them all, no matter how few files need to be checked.